# Access data/file on Sharepoint Online in c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365api

I need to connect my web app to a sharepoint online. I read a lot of example based on on-premise SHP ed it use a Sharepoint.DLL. So MS suggest to use Graph.

My question is about best practice to implement this function:

- read a list of files/folder List item
- create folder
- (opt) upload document

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be, develop a REST API flow using MS Flow... the MS Flow action would be when a http request comes.... then in the MS Flow handle the files reading and files uploading functionality and once you save the the flow you will get an automatic Azure REST API URL - this api you have to call from your c# code and need to pass the parameter to REST api.      Note:
1.You may need to develop two MS Flow api one is for reading the items and another for uploading the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access SharePoint Online data using C# in your web app, you could choose SharePoint Online CSOM library:

[Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/)

Read List Item and other objects:

[How To Read Various Objects Using SharePoint Online Client Side Object Model (CSOM)](https://www.fmtconsultants.com/sharepoint-online-client-side-object-model/)

Create folder:

[Create Folder in SharePoint using CSOM](http://www.codesharepoint.com/csom/create-folder-in-sharepoint-using-csom)

Upload document:

[CSOM. Upload document](http://blog.vitalyzhukov.ru/en/csom-upload-document)